# Azure web service root domain works but not www subdomain

Tags: azure, ssl, dns

I have an Azure web app to which I have mapped a custom domain from another registrar. The root domain works fine and is secured with a (free) Azure SSL cert. I have not been able to get the www. subdomain to work. (It is also secured with an Azure SSL cert.)

I have followed these three articles that detail the method to [Map an existing custom DNS name to Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain?tabs=a%2Cazurecli#3-create-the-dns-records), [Add a TLS/SSL certificate in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate?tabs=apex%2Cportal#create-a-free-managed-certificate), and [Secure a custom DNS name with a TLS/SSL binding in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-bindings).

When I browse to the example web app, astroguru.com, it displays a simple blazor server starter page as it should. If I browse to [www.astroguru.com](http://www.astroguru.com), I get a page not found with info icon in the address bar that says the site is not secure, as shown below:
[image]

Below are the DNS records that I have created exactly as described in the first article ref'd above, which include (and see image below):

- an A record pointing to the IP address of the web service.
- a TXT record containing the verification ID
- a CNAME record for the www subdomain that the tutorials say must
  point to the original site name (e.g. astroguru.azurewebsites.net)
- along with another TXT record with the hostname asuid.www and the
  same verification ID.
  [image: DNS Records]

The image below shows the two secured URLs from the Azure portal.
[image: Custom Domain Names]

The image below shows the two private key certs in the Azure portal that secure the two URLs above:
[image: Privat Key Certs]

Can someone tell me what I've done wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Had to recreate the certificate and rebind.